# When making chicken soup, should I reuse the vegetables I used to make the broth?

Tags: soup, broth

When making a chicken broth I'll chuck in some onion, carrots, celery, leeks, whatever I got lying around.

When I make the soup, I usually strain out all the bones and veggies in the broth and put in new vegetables along with the meat. Should I be transferring any of the veggies from the broth into the soup or putting in all fresh veggies?

Comment: Just personal choice. There is no right or wrong with this

Comment: One thing you might want to consider is pureeing the cooked vegetables just to give the soup a bit more body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely just a matter of preference. I'd expect the vegetables from the stock to be overcooked for my tastes, I like a little texture in my soup.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can reuse the vegetables just fine. I mean why waste food. Reusing the vegetables shouldn't alter the taste of the soup in an adverse way.